# Посчитать количество женщин и мужчин по спортивным секциям

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Необходимо посчитать количество мужчин и женщин в каждой секции в спорт. клубе. Структура вывода: Секция1 - количество мужчин - количество женщин
Секция2 - количество мужчин - количество женщин и т.д.

Я написал такой запрос:

```
                    var result = from sec in db.SECTIONS
                         from cis in db.CLIENT_IN_SECTION
                         from client in db.CLIENTS
                         where sec.SECTION_ID == cis.CIS_SECTION_ID && cis.CIS_CLIENT_ID == client.CLIENT_ID
                         group new {sec, client} by new {sec.SECTION_ID, client.CLIENT_SEX} into g


                         select new SecondQuery
                         {

                             Section = g.Select(x => x.sec.SECTION_NAME).FirstOrDefault(),
                             CountMen = g.Count(x=> x.client.CLIENT_SEX == "М"),
                             CountWomen = g.Count(x => x.client.CLIENT_SEX == "Ж")
                         };
```

Результатом вывода стало: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, запрос работает, только выводит результат для женщин и мужчин в две разные строки. Как сделать так, чтобы все считалось в одну строку?

Comment: `dbConttext.Sections.Select(section=>new {section.Name, M = section.Clients.Where(мужик).Count(), G= section.Clients.Where(женщина).Count()})`

Comment: Информация о поле человека хранится в таблице CLIENTS, в SECTIONS хранится только Id и название секции, в таблице CLIENTS_IN_SECTIONS хранятся Id Клиента и Id Секции. Так что такой запрос, как у Вас, не выйдет

Comment: У вас Entity Framework? Вы используете навигационные свойства? У вас внешние ключи на таблицах прописаны?

Comment: Да, все верно. Конечно, прописаны

Comment: Вы используете навигационные свойства?